# A necessary and sufficient condition of norm euclidean

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose that $(E,\, \|~\|)$ is a normed vector space. Prove that $\|~\|$ is an Euclidean norm, i.e., it exists an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ s.t. $\forall x \in E$, $⟨x, x⟩ = \| x \|^2 \ $, iff  $$\forall (a, b) \in \mathbb{R}^2, ~\forall (x, y) \in E^2,~~ \| x\| = \| y \| \implies \| ax+by \| = \|bx + ay\|.$$

The "$\implies$" part is simple. I have trouble working on the other way. I'm thinking of proving that the condition is equivalent to the identity of parallelogram. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! With Euclidean norm you mean the usual definition of norm in Euclidean space?

Comment: If your space is not $\mathbb R^{n}$ or $\mathbb C^{n}$ the Euclidean norm on it does not make sense.

Comment: @pojoo If you ask a question, you should at least be sure what the terminology means. I therefore voted to close your question. If you can clarify it, edit your question and it can be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to define a candidate for the scalar product via polarization,
$$
g(x,y)=\frac12(\|x+y\|^2-\|x\|^2-\|y\|^2)
$$
or
$$
g(x,y)=\frac14(\|x+y\|^2-\|x-y\|^2)
$$
and prove the linearity in the first argument with the given property. The positivity follows directly from the construction.